# I need to generate a series of months within a select

Tags: postgresql, redash

I work with PostgreSQL integrated into Redash, and am currently needing to do the following report:

> - generate active_month for each subscription in the database, following the rule: for each month in the last 12, if that month falls in between the subscription's creation and cancelation date, create a line with that month as 'active_month'
> - report should contain count of subscriptions on each active_month, filtered by unit

My current code uses a nested select and looks like the following:

```
select
  unit,
  active_month,
  subscriptions
from
  (
    select
      unit_id unit,
      to_char(
        date_trunc('month', created_at) :: timestamp :: date,
        'YYYY-MM'
      ) active_month,
      count(id) subscriptions
    from
      [DATABASE HERE]
    where
      created_at >= (timestamp '{{ today }}' - interval '12 months')
    group by
      created_at,
      unit
    order by
      active_month,
      unit_id
  ) inner_query
group by
  active_month,
  unit,
  subscriptions
order by
  active_month,
  unit
```

However, this doesn't work, as:

1. It only takes into consideration the creation month, and not every month for which the subscription was active
2. It seems to be counting different dates from the same month as different fields, since there are multiple lines with the same unit and month on them

Any suggestions about how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add some sample data of your tables including the desired output for this data? This would make your question far easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the [Date Range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) for the months you are interested in (With CTE or sub-select) then use the [element contained](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html) operator for appropriate date selection. [See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d6206f2ee5b2147fffa958ab18221c70), of course I just generated random data and it is dependent on my actually understanding what you are asking. Which is questionable!

```
with  calendar (date_range) as 
     ( select daterange ( (current_date-interval '12 months')::date
                         , current_date 
                         , '[]' 
                         ) 
     ) --select * calendar; 
select
  unit,
  active_month,
  subscriptions
from
  (
    select
      unit_id unit,
      to_char(
        date_trunc('month', created_at) :: timestamp :: date,
        'YYYY-MM'
      ) active_month,
      count(id) subscriptions
    from
       DATABASE_HERE
    where
      created_at::date <@ (select date_range from calendar)  --<<<< change  
        
    group by
      created_at,
      unit
    order by
      active_month,
      unit_id
  ) inner_query
group by
  active_month,
  unit,
  subscriptions
order by
  active_month,
  unit;
```

Comment: This still  has the issue of only retrieving the creation month, though...

Comment: Then you need to post table descriptions (ddl), test data, expected results and the current results of that data. as text - **no images**. Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12).  You would aslo benefit by taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com) and reviewing [ask].